# Notifying users of new records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a website which containing a downloads area .I want to notify users when any new file uploaded to this section .

I have thought of 2 ways to do this.

The first is to store the date & time that users last visited the events and downloads pages in a database table; so the schema would look something like:

```
Table `account_page_visits`:
    page_id INT NOT NULL,
    account_id INT NOT NULL,
    last_visited DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

There is also a downloads table and an events table. In these tables, there would be a column called `date_added` which would store the date and time the record was added to the table.

At the point of fetching my links from the database (stored in a `navigation` table) I would check each link and if the link is downloads or events, I would count the number of downloads or events where their `date_added` is greater than the `last_visited` time of the page for the current user.

This is actually the method I have implemented at the moment, but I have discovered a problem:

The downloads and events pages are split into sub pages whereby the number of downloads or events returned from the database is limited to 20 per page. The current notification method assumes that once the user has visited the events or downloads page, they have effectively "seen" all new downloads or events as the `last_visited` time will now be greater than the `date_added` of the new downloads / events. If the user only visits page 1 of downloads and then goes to another page, they wont see any more notifications for downloads even though they have only seen 20 new downloads.

The second method fixes this problem, but seems long winded to me:

Instead of a `account_page_visits` table, I would have `viewed_downloads` and `viewed_events` tables. These would contain the event/download id and the account id. I would get the number of unseen downloads / events by seeing if a record existed in `viewed_downloads` or `viewed_events`; something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `downloads` d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `viewed_downloads` vd
    WHERE vd.download_id = d.id
    AND vd.account_id = userAccountId
)
```

Records would be added to the `viewed_downloads` and `viewed_events` tables when the downloads / events are selected when the user visits the downloads / events page in some kind of SELECT - INSERT IGNORE

which approach would be better ?

Comment: I can not understrand what you want please be a brief do you want to notify user when a new file uploaded to your downloads area ?or get count of how many people downloaded your files ?

Comment: Sorry this is to notify users that a new file has been uploaded and is available for them to download

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question in a good way so the best solution is to add a new records to your downloads table on is `ViewsCount` which will be updated every time a user download you item and `LastVisted` and this alos will be updated every time when you are trying to get this account most downloaded files you can use a simple select statement to get the most download files for this account that would be the best solution if i understand your question in a good way

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I must not have worded my question quite right. This is to notify users that a new download or event has been added for them to view or download, similar to how Facebook notifies users that someone has posted in a group they are part of

Comment: actually you do not need to create at trigger or something all you need to do is when you are uploading your file in the same step you need to notify users when upload complete then in the same transaction send notifications to the users that a new file has been uploaded .